# Wrapping \obeylines with \halign into a macro

Tags: tex-core, horizontal-alignment, plain-tex

In the TeXbook, Knuth gives an example:

> Are you tired of typing `\cr`? You can get plain TEX to insert an automatic `\cr` at the end of each input line in the following way:
>
> ```
> \begingroup \let\par=\cr \obeylines %
> \halign{⟨preamble⟩
> ⟨ﬁrst line of alignment⟩
> ...
> ⟨last line of alignment}\endgroup
> ```

How would one wrap this up into a macro? So that one could use:

```
\mytable{%
This & is & the & first & row
This & is & the & second & row
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might be missing a technical issue, but the following seems to work. I simply replaced Joseph's construction of the preamble by the preamble itself, with doubled hash signs because we are inside a definition.

The key point (taken from Joseph's answer) is to use one macro (`\mytable`) to do `\obeylines` (i.e. set up the catcode for the newline character), *before* reading the argument with a different macro, `\mytableAux`.

```
\def\mytable{%
  \begingroup
    \let\par=\cr
    \obeylines
    \mytableAux
}
\def\mytableAux#1{%
    \halign{##&##&##&##&##\cr#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\mytable{%
This & is & the & first & row
This & is & the & second & row
}
\bye
```

Comment: Indeed, it seems to work. Simply awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For example

```
\def\mytable{%
  \begingroup
    \let\par=\cr
    \obeylines
    \mytableAux
}
\def\mytableAux#1{%
    \mytoks=\expandafter{\the\myhash}%
    \mytoks=\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      {\expandafter\the\expandafter\myhash\expandafter&\the\mytoks}%
    \mytoks=\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      {\expandafter\the\expandafter\myhash\expandafter&\the\mytoks}%
    \mytoks=\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      {\expandafter\the\expandafter\myhash\expandafter&\the\mytoks}%
    \mytoks=\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      {\expandafter\the\expandafter\myhash\expandafter&\the\mytoks\cr#1}%
    \halign\expandafter{\the\mytoks}%
  \endgroup
}
\newtoks\mytoks
\newtoks\myhash
\myhash={#}
\mytable{%
This & is & the & first & row
This & is & the & second & row
}
\bye
```

A lot of the work here is about constructing the template: I've not used a loop or anything subtle, although in a real application you would do. (For example, see how LaTeX2e constructs the `\halign` template for tabulars.) You need to have the `\halign` within the group which sets up `^^M=\cr`, as this cannot be expanded to do the substitution.

Comment: Oh man, that seems more trouble than it's worth. Thanks, though!